# When debugging ArcGIS add-in, can't use "Edit and Continue"

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio, debugging

I've been working on this add-in for years, and just today set up a new computer with VS 2013 and ArcGIS 10.3.  When I run my add-in from the debugger, breakpoints can be hit, but I can't edit when code execution is paused - I get an error, "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded".

I've done all the suggestions I could find in various forums:

Change build output path to bin\

verify that Configuration = Debug

verify that Platform = x86

Edit and Continue enabled (Tools > Options)

checked "Break all processes when one process breaks"

unchecked "Require source files to exactly match the original version"

Anything else I can try?

---

When I make a simple Windows Forms application, I can successfully "Edit and Continue". –  kev_gis 1 hour ago

I'm not sure how to get an ArcMap SDK installed for Visual Studio 2013. I installed "ArcGIS_Runtime_SDK_DotNet_1025.exe" as well as "ArcObjects_SDK_for_NET_Framework_1022_140467.exe". When I try to make a new Add-In in Visual Studio 2013, I do not see ArcGIS under the list of available templates.

After attempting to install the SDKs listed above, now I get a "No Debugging Information" error message when attempting to run.  "Debugging information for 'ArcMap.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file."

I've gone through all of the steps I could find on this page, with no effect:
[Why can't the breakpoint be "hit" when debugging an ArcGIS 10 Add-In?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13606/why-cant-the-breakpoint-be-hit-when-debugging-an-arcgis-10-add-in#16206)